# Save selected language in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, local-storage

I have the following code everything is looking correct but I can not keep the language in localstorage.

```
state = {
  lang: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lang")) || en
};

selectLanguage = e => {
  const langKey = e.target.value;
  this.setState(
    { lang: languages[langKey] },
    localStorage.setItem("lang", JSON.stringify(this.state.lang))
  );
};
```

the console.log msg is

```
localStorage
  Storage {lang: "[object Object]", length: 1}
    lang: "[object Object]"
      length: 1
  __proto__: Storage
```

I have tried to load the saved lang without JSON.parse but again same problem.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: What is the value of `languages`, is it a big JSON file or what?

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/zq3rafxp/

Comment: It is a big JSON file and I'm using context API to change it all over the app

Comment: to debug, try adding an anonymous fn as the callback after setState, to make sure state is what you think it is when setting lang to local storage. ```this.setState(
    { lang: languages[langKey] }, () => { console.log('STATE', this.state)
    localStorage.setItem("lang", JSON.stringify(this.state.lang))}
  );```

Comment: For me I'm getting an error that I can't access the json file, it shows undefined when I'm trying to access any value from the json

Comment: Was your problem solved by the answer I posted?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's a good idea to stringify `state` property of your ReactJS component? You should also know that the second argument of `setState` expects a function (as it is defined here https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L58) but you're submitting `undefined` which is the result of `localStorage.setItem(...)`.

The optional callback of `setState` is going to be executed as soon as the state object is really updated, meaning that the value of `this.state.lang` will probably be the current one instead of the new selected language. Either way, here's my recommendation.

First, double check that the `languages` value is what you expected and do this:

```
this.setState({
    lang: languages[langKey]
}, function() {
    /**
     * Safe to access state
     */
    localStorage.setItem('lang', JSON.stringify(this.state.lang));
});
```

Don't worry since the callback function keeps the context of the current component, which means it's safe to access state through `this`.

You need to also handle the situation where `JSON.parse` will fail because there's invalid information in it, if you don't handle it, your whole application will fail to render properly.

I am not sure about your needs but I also believe that waiting for the state to change is unnecessary, you can simply do this:

```
const langObject = languages[langKey]
this.setState({
    lang: langObject
});
/**
 * Not necessary to wait until state is updated
 */
localStorage.setItem('lang', JSON.stringify(langObject));
```

Be aware that there's a limit for the maximum capacity of localStorage, you might not want to use it as much as possible to avoid bordering that limit.